Making a forest tree fit the page width?
Is there a way to specify that you'd like the tree to stretch across the entire textwidth? In other words, to make the leftmost node align with the left margin, and the rightmost with the right margin, and then have everything in between drawn relative to those points?
Here's a MWE of the tree I'm trying to fit;
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{forest}
    [IP$_{<t>}$
        [VP$_{<<e,t>,t>}$
            [NP $_{<<<e,t>,e,t>>,t>}$
                [at least five $_{<<e,t>,<<<e,t>,<e,t>>,t>>}$]
                [NP $_{<e,t>}$
                    [students $_{<<e,t>,<e,t>>}$]
                    [$t_{2_{<e,t>}}$]
                ]
            ]
            [arrived $_{<e,t>}$]
        ]
        [CP$_{<e,t>}$
            [who$_1$]
            [CP$_{<t>}$
                [$t_{1_{<e>}}$]
                [VP $_{<e,t>}$
                    [took $_{<e,<e,t>>}$]
                    [semantics $_{<e>}$]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{center}

\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.se and thanks for including a sample document. I don't think there's a way to do this automatically (unless you used \resizebox from graphicx, but that's not a good idea. You can add for tree={s sep=.5in} to the tree to widen everything, and adjust the value as required.

Unrelated, but t and e should not be enclosed in <...>.

You could, I think, @AlanMunn ? How do I know where I need < or >? What size paper? TeX Live defaults to A4. article defaults to US letter. geometry ...

I think I've corrected the representation of basic types, if I've understood correctly. Since I'm not a linguist and don't actually know what this means, take that for what it is worth.
I've added for tree={draw} and showframe just for demonstration purposes. Since Okular has a bug which ruins images, you'll have to either compile it or imagine it to actually see the demonstration, but I've thoroughly tested it on a sample of n trees where n=1. Since the one is your tree, it does at least work in this case.
The style
widen tree to width=<dimension expression>

takes a single, optional argument. If unspecified, the default value is 0pt so the style will have no effect.
Notes

The algorithm attempts to be conservative. This means it will be slow if you apply the style to many trees. I recommend memoize.

It is not so conservative it won't break in extreme cases. For these purposes, an 'extreme case' is any case in which the algorithm fails.

Do not leave this to compile unattended. If it goes wrong, it may enter an eternal forest loop. I don't think this will happen. As explained in (1), I've exhaustively tested it, but you can't be too careful.

I've told the algorithm to stop when the difference between the tree and the target is no more than 1pt. Do not change this to 0pt. TeX's calculations are only approximate. Reducing the allowance to 0pt will trigger an infinite loop.

No allowance is made for labels, edges or node borders. If your tree features any of these things and they protrude width-wise, you must adjust the target width accordingly.

I don't recommend this on aesthetic or efficiency grounds. I'm not sure why you'd want a tree of specified width particularly. But maybe I just lack imagination.


Caveat emptor ...
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=.75in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\forestset{% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/715314/
  declare dimen register=target wd,
  target wd'=0pt,
  declare dimen register=needed wd,
  needed wd'=0pt,
  adjust tree/.style={
    tempcounta'=1,
    tempcountc'=0,
    for tree breadth-first={%
      if={ >OR> {level}{tempcountc} }{
        tempcountc/.option=level,
        tempcountd'=1,
      }{
        tempcountd'+=1,
        if={ >RR> {tempcountd}{tempcounta} }{
          tempcounta/.register=tempcountd,
        }{},
      },
    },
    tempcounta*/.register=tempcountc,
    tempcounta'+=1,
    tempdima/.process={ RRw2+d {needed wd}{tempcounta}{##1/##2} },
    where={>O_<{s}{0pt}}{
      s-/.register=tempdima,
    }{
      s+/.register=tempdima,
    },
    compute xy stage,
    tempdima/.max={>OOw2+d{x}{max x}{##1+##2}}{tree},
    tempdimb/.min={>OOw2+d{x}{min x}{##1+##2}}{tree},
    tempdimc/.register=tempdima,
    tempdimc-/.register=tempdimb,
    needed wd/.register=target wd,
    needed wd-/.register=tempdimc,
    if={ >Rd>{needed wd}{1pt} }
    {% pam alla i ddim ddefnyddio loop yma?
      adjust tree,
    }{},
  },
  widen tree to width/.style={
    target wd=#1,
    needed wd/.register=target wd,
    before drawing tree={
      tempdima/.max={>OOw2+d{x}{max x}{##1+##2}}{tree},
      tempdimb/.min={>OOw2+d{x}{min x}{##1+##2}}{tree},
      tempdimc/.register=tempdima,
      tempdimc-/.register=tempdimb,
      needed wd-/.register=tempdimc,
      if={ >Rd>{needed wd}{1pt} }
      {% pam alla i ddim ddefnyddio loop yma?
        adjust tree,
      }{},
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{forest}
    widen tree to width=\linewidth,
    for tree={draw},
    [IP$_{t}$ 
      [VP$_{<<e,t>,t>}$
        [NP $_{<<<e,t>,e,t>>,t>}$
          [at least five $_{<<e,t>,<<<e,t>,<e,t>>,t>>}$]
          [NP $_{<e,t>}$
            [students $_{<<e,t>,<e,t>>}$]
            [$t_{2_{<e,t>}}$]
          ]
        ]
        [arrived $_{<e,t>}$]
      ]
      [CP$_{<e,t>}$
        [who$_1$]
        [CP$_{t}$
          [$t_{1_{e}}$]
          [VP $_{<e,t>}$
            [took $_{<e,<e,t>>}$]
            [semantics $_{e}$]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  \end{forest}
\end{center}

\end{document}



I wanted to use a loop, but I couldn't get it to work ....
